# System: job_mig_spawn() can't find its session

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, unix, launchd

I want to launch cocoa application from root process in particular user.So i am changing owner and permission of my application.

If the s group of permissions has the user bit set (corresponding to u+s), then whenever anyone executes that program, the process takes on the privileges of whoever owns it.

```
sudo chown -R test myApp
sudo chmod u+s /Contents/MacOS/myApp
system([@"open myApp" UTF8String]);  //inside root process
//-rwsr-xr-x  1 test  myApp
```

Error:

```
com.apple.launchd[1]: System: Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:8760 (24498):0
com.apple.launchd[1]: System: job_mig_spawn() can't find its session!
open[24459]: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=5 label=[0x0-0x274274].
rootProcess[23127]: LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/myApp.app/.
```

can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You should read all of [Technical Note TN2083: Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html), but in particular, it says this:

> A common question we get in [Apple Developer Technical Support] is "How can I launch a GUI application from my daemon?" The answer is that you can't.

Comment: but i am able to launch GUI application in one logged-in user.

Comment: Read the technote. It explains.

Comment: From documentation: " A daemon can't launch a GUI application because the daemon is running in the wrong context. Even if it could choose which context to run the GUI application in, which would it choose?" If i will specify GUI contexts to daemon?

Comment: Knowing the username is not enough to identify the context. There may not *be* a context. The technote explains the right approach: "The correct solution to this problem is to split your program into multiple components …. So, you might have a daemon for managing the global state and an agent operating on behalf of each of the logged in users. …"

Comment: I have monitor(in user mode) and daemon(in root), in monitor i am cathing SIGSEGV singnal and writting backtrace into file. I want to relaunch monitor after SIGSEGV.

Comment: Use a launchd agent and tell launchd to keep your agent alive. If it exits, launchd will restart it.

Comment: but i have quit option in my monitor.

Comment: Then use an agent, separate from your monitor, to relaunch the monitor under just the circumstances you desire.